# Why can't I downcast a map to a type who's key is a subtype of the original map's key

Tags: scala

Why does this fail:

```
val h = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Integer,String]()
val g:collection.mutable.HashMap[Number,String] = h
```

when this succeeds:

```
 val i:Integer = 10
 val n:Number = i
```

and

```
val g:collection.mutable.HashMap[Number,String] = h.asInstanceOf[ collection.mutable.HashMap[Number,String] ]
```

always has the correct behavior (for g).

h's key objects is guaranteed to have the same behavior as expected by g's keys, so it seems always safe to use h as a g. So why does the compiler disallow this cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key types of `Map`s are not covariant. If you check scaladoc, the type declaration of *immutable* map is `Map[A, +B]` (notice `A` doesn't have a `+`). The reason is that suppose the compiler allowed your assignment from `h` to `g`, then it will be possible to write the following:

```
g.get(1.234)
```

since `1.234` is a `Number`. Yet `g` is really `h`, and `h` only expect the keys to be integers.

For similar reasons, if your map is mutable (as yours is), then the value type is not covariant either.